# Is a bitwise Access Control List considered an Anti-pattern?

Tags: php, user-interface

Is a bitwise Access Control List considered an Anti-pattern? I'm curious because I see this in an application I am working on and although it seems funny it kinda works, whats the general consensus. The downside I see in it is that it is hard to know what permission 8 is it would be easier to see "editor" or "manager". But the bitwise approach seems to work on a technical level.

Comment: You seem to be conflating the implementation approach with the specifics of it. There's no reason why named constants couldn't be used instead of hard-coding bit locations. Also, how many bits? Is it fixed in size, or can it grow indefinitely?

Comment: thanks for the response. The background story is that I never considered this approach before, but i am working for a company that implements this and I wanted to know what the benefits were to using the approach. To me it is very obfuscating and not easy to document but like I said it works. I wanted to argue against using it but it looks like people use this a lot, so I guess i am learning something new. I prefer an ACL that relates to columns in a DB with enum flags 1,0 for yes no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It saves storage space, and it's used everywhere. It's perfect for cases where you have one person who is both an "editor" and a "manager", for example. And you shouldn't have to remember what permission 8 is, you should have names that refer to those numbers that you define once and then don't have to worry about.

Comment: thanks for the response, I was unaware of how prevalent this approach in ACL's was. I feel enlightened.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an anti-pattern, but it does have some significant gotchas to be aware of:

- Using bitfields for access control makes it impossible to efficiently list the objects that a given user has access to. (Searching for `canRead = 1` can be indexed in SQL, but `permissions & 0x40 = 0x40` cannot.)
- There are a limited number of bits in an integer. Make sure you'll never need more than 31. (Using the sign bit is messy, and PHP doesn't have 64-bit integers when running on 32-bit systems.) In fact, avoid using them for anything that's dynamically allocated -- it's probably best to only use them for built-in permissions.
- Bitmasks are much harder to read in a database console.

All around, you're probably much better off using a bunch of individual `TINYINT` (or similar) flags in the database. The storage savings from packing values into bitfields are unlikely to be worth the hassle.

Comment: I think posgresql can index on any expression, not just columns.

Comment: Correct, but with some difficulty. I believe you'd have to index `permissions & X` separately for each value of `X` you needed; a single index on `permissions` wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an official consensus but since if it's not using a string in some clever way I would consider it an anti-pattern since you'd be limited to the number of bits used by the particular numeric type.

You may know the scope of your project well enough to know for sure that you'll never have more than 32/64 though.

The readability of the permission values isn't cause for much concern.